# Unstable wireless on MacBook 2,1 with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, networking, wireless, macbook

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 as the sole OS on my old white MacBook 2,1.

The wireless seems really unstable. The signal is always full, but sometimes I can browse, sometimes I can't. Sometimes I can download updates, sometimes they stop. I am using another laptop right next to it, and the network on that is flawless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following commands and was sceptical whether it would work. But it has been flawless and has solved my issues with my wireless on Macbook 2.1.

```
root@ubuntu:~# ifconfig wlan0 down  
root@ubuntu:~# rmmod -f ath9k
root@ubuntu:~# sudo modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

WARNING: All config files need .conf: `/etc/modprobe.d/bad_list`. It will be ignored in a future release.

```
root@ubuntu:~# ifconfig wlan0 up
```